# Down votes of user accounts temporarily suspended for voting irregularities

Tags: support, downvotes, account-suspension, sock-puppets

I apologize if this has been addressed before, but I couldn't find a dup.

I'm aware of a user that was recently suspended for voting irregularities because they had a sock puppet up voting their answers. It was obvious to me because I would see their poor answers constantly getting up votes. I also suspect that the same sock puppet account was used to down vote many of my answers because we frequently answered questions with the same tag.

I know that any fraudulent up votes by the sock puppet will be removed, but what about all the **suspect down votes** I may have received from the sock puppet? It was over several months so I suspect the down votes wouldn't be caught by serial down-voting algorithm.

Comment: Did they target just you or was it everyone (except the sock owner) that got downvotes? If it wasn't just you then the votes probably won't be reversed.

Comment: As I understand it, the serial rollback is fairly conservative and not exactly equipped to look at a long history of votes over time.  This tells me that you're unlikely to get any votes by a long-lived serial downvoter overturned since their signal isn't discernible from the noise of a typical user voting on things.  That said, if the sock puppet accounts are actually deleted, then those votes will be invalidated.

Comment: I'm not really sure. OFC I used to feel like I was getting targeted, but there may have been others.

Comment: These voting patterns are very hard to distinguish from normal ones. Users that visit the same [tag] quite often vote on each other's posts. Not always positively. If a sock account was used to vote on yours then the destruction of the account also cancels the DVs. So you have in fact pretty decent evidence that this did not actually happen.  You've had 9 voting reversal this month but they were canceled upvotes, not downvotes.  Jumping to conclusions is pretty easy when you can't know who voted

Comment: if downvoter is smart enough it can pass undetected, until the sock puppet account gets deleted.

Comment: When deleting a sock puppet, IMO, I think that every single vote caste from the sock puppet SHOULD be removed. Why would his older votes be more trusted than his recent ones ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier deleting account typically also deletes all votes they cast, up and down. There are exceptional cases ([discussed eg here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/165773)) when votes are preserved but this is currently done only per manual review of SE team and most likely doesn't involve preserving sock puppet votes (because why would they do so)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Both the up and down votes cast by an account will be removed.

If the downvotes that you received weren't removed, assuming they haven't already been reversed by the algorithm, then they weren't cast by that sock puppet account in the first place.

(Seeing a "User was removed" record resulting in net rep gain in your rep history that coincides with another user's "User was removed" record resulting in net rep loss doesn't guarantee that the two events were the result of the same account deletion, but *not* seeing such a record in your history does preclude it altogether.)